# @ManyToOne and @OneToOne relations with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, one-to-many

I am trying to change the id of my database entities from a single long to a composite id consisting of two long's which are encapsulated in my ID.class shown below. What annotations would you use for ManyToOne and OneToMany relations? Did I made a mistake with my annotations, especially with @JoinColumns, @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId. My problem is that relations are stored with null;

My ID class consist of an autogenerated long (pid) and a manually set secondary long (sid). This is the ID for all my entity classes:

```
@Embeddable
public class ID implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long pid;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private long sid;
}
```

My Entity-class (example) has a many-to-one relation to Office a one-to-one relation to Settings (both relations are uni-directional).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "office_pid", referencedColumnName = "pid", updatable=false, insertable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "office_sid", referencedColumnName = "sid", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    })
    private Office office;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "setting_pid", referencedColumnName = "pid", updatable=false, insertable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "setting_sid", referencedColumnName = "sid", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    })
    private Settings setting;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Account> accounts= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Office class (Many-To-One example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "office")
public class Office {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ID id;
    @Column(length = 128)
    private String description;

}
```

Account class (One-To-Many example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ID id;
    @Column(length = 16)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_pid", referencedColumnName = "pid"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_sid", referencedColumnName = "sid")
    })
    private User user;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequencing shouldn't be used if you want a composite pk - use only the sequence generated field which is unique, or composite business fields that are unique.

Second issue is the joinColumn definitions in User.  You have marked them as updatable=false, insertable=false which means the foreign keys cannot be changed through the mappings, and is why they are always null regardless of setting the relationship.  Remove the updatable=false, insertable=false settings from each to have the fields set when you set the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I removed all updatable=false and insertable=false and I looks promising. But now I am stucked with the @OneToMany relations. What annotation do I need there?

Comment: For now, I am not changing the sequencing as it works pretty well for me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean when you say you are stuck with @OneToMany relations.  You were using ManyToOne and OneToOne in the code - changing the insertable, updatable flags does not mean you need to change your mappings unless you had those fields mapped through another mapping as well.

Comment: My entites also have @OneToMany as well. I didn't mentioned it because I thought it works. But I was wrong. I updated the code in my first post with an example of an OneToMany relation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OneToMany mapping shown. My guess now is that you have a bidirectional relationship and are making the common mistake of only setting one side.  When you update the Account.user, you must also add that account to the user.accounts list