# How can I specify the generated column name in the DDL for my derived identifier with JPA2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hbm2ddl

We have codes in a database that have a compound identifier (here category+code), and code parameters in another table that have the same two identifiers + a parameter name (so category+code+name)

We use @IdClass for the identifiers. Here is the code:

**Code.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CodeId.class)
public class Code implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String category;

    @Id
    private String code;

    private Date validFrom;
    private Date validUntil;

    public String getCategory() { return category; }
    public String getCode() { return code; }
    public Date getValidFrom() { return validFrom; }
    public Date getValidUntil() { return validUntil; }
}
```

**CodeId.java**

```
public class CodeId implements Serializable {

    private String category;
    private String code;

    public CodeId() {
    }

    public CodeId(String category, String code) {
        this.category = category;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCategory() { return category; }
    public String getCode() { return code; }
}
```

**CodeParam.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(CodeParamId.class)
public class CodeParam implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Code code;

    @Id
    private String name;

    private String value;

    public Code getCode() { return code; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

**CodeParamId.java**

```
public class CodeParamId implements Serializable {

    private CodeId code;
    private String name;

    public CodeParamId() {
    }

    public CodeParamId(CodeId code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CodeId getCode() { return code; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

---

So, this works quite good. The problem we are having is for our unit tests, when we generate a HSQLDB in-memory DB and create the schema using the entities, using hbm2ddl. Here is the generated DDL:

```
create table Code (
    category varchar(255) not null,
    code varchar(255) not null,
    validFrom timestamp,
    validUntil timestamp,
    primary key (category, code)
)

create table CodeParam (
    name varchar(255) not null,
    code_category varchar(255),
    code_code varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (code_category, code_code, name)
)

alter table CodeParam 
    add constraint FK_mvkuf50rko4mipw1sb7r9yidk 
    foreign key (code_category, code_code) 
    references Code
```

How can I change the names generated for the derived identifiers in the CodeParam table (here **code_category** and **code_code**) ?

I need to have "category" instead of "code_category" and "code" instead of "code_code".

I tried overriding the @ManyToOne association using @AssociationOverride but couldn't find anything that did that.

I'm also assuming this would be easier using @EmbeddedId and the likes, but I need to know if it is possible using @IdClass this way.

Comment: Is it not possible to use **@Column(name = "category")**

Comment: On `private Code code` in CodeParam ? Because it is not possible to mix @ManyToOne with @Column

Comment: looked at @JoinColumns? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264994/manytoone-and-onetoone-relations-with-embeddedid

Comment: Yeah, I tried everything I could think of yesterday.. or so I thought. Tried again and it does indeed work with the correct annotation : `@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "category", name = "category"), @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "code", name = "code") })`

Comment: I am happy for you that you have solved your problem :)

Comment: Thank you for making me try that again ! You could write the answer and I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to **private Code code** in CodeParam

```
@JoinColumns({ 
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "category", name = "category"),   
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "code", name = "code") })
```

Comment: Just to add on this answer: the reason it didn't work for me at first was because I thought I add to put "code.category" in the referencedColumnName instead of just "category"